# adding auto-incrementing column in active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to add an integer based auto-incrementing column to my table in postgresql and then access it through active record.  It keeps getting set to NULL by active record.

Obvious approach:

```
add_column :table_name, :id_name, :primary_key
```

This doesn't work because the table already has a primary key.

Next I tried adding this to the up part of the Active Record migration:

```
execute("ALTER TABLE table_name ADD id_name SERIAL;")
```

That works perfectly in creating the table and if I create a new entry through the db directly id_name is set as one would hope.  However if I make a new entry through ActiveRecord by using .new & .save or .create it blows up as it tries to set id_name to null.

I've also tried:

```
execute("CREATE SEQUENCE table_name_id_name_seq;")
execute("ALTER TABLE table_name ADD id_name INTEGER DEFAULT NEXTVAL('table_name_id_name_seq');")
execute("ALTER SEQUENCE table_name_id_name_seq OWNED BY table_name.id_name;")
```

That allows .new & .save as well as .create to make an entry, but the result has id_name of null.

Is there any way to convince Rails not to override the default db value with null?

Comment: Did you have a look at gem "sequenced" (https://github.com/djreimer/sequenced). Does exactly what you're looking for...

Comment: Adding an entry through the PG gem results in id_name being set correctly as long as I pass DEFAULT instead of null.

Comment: @Danny Thanks for the link - looking through it.  I'd like the incrementing to happen at the db layer if possible.

Comment: @Danny That works great for new rows, however all the old rows are left a null.  I need to do something which creates the id on every row in the table including new ones.  Thank you though.  It was almost a solution!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hacky, but here's a solution that works:

```
def up   
  add_column :table_name, :id_name, :integer
  n = 1
  TableName.all.each_with_index do |name|
    name.id_name = n
    name.save
    n += 1
  end
  execute "CREATE SEQUENCE table_name_id_name_seq START #{n} OWNED BY table_name.id_name;"
end


def next_seq_value(sequence)
  Article.connection.execute("SELECT nextval('#{sequence}')")[0]['nextval']
end


before_validation(:on => :create) do
  unless attribute_present?("id_name")
    self.id_name = next_seq_value('table_name_id_name_seq')
  end
 end
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem with having the database auto-increment a column by using type serial is that it is not supported by the schema.db, so you won't be able to have that feature populate the test database, for example.

Instead, here is a database-agnostic way of supporting an incrementing column:

```
  before_create :increment_identifier

  def increment_identifier
    sql = "SELECT COALESCE(MAX(identifier), 0) + 1 FROM claims"
    self.identifier = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql).values[0][0]
  end
```

The `COALESCE` is just returning 0 instead of nil for an empty table. And the `values[0][0]` is the necessary way to access the funky object returned by ActiveRecord.Base.

Comment: The issue with this solution is that it is not compatible with parallels requests. This is a logical callback, not a physical callback directly queued in the database order processes of the requests.